# How can I compare the average of a list with every element in the same list?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

```
fun promedio l = let
    fun sl(nil, sum, len) = sum div len
    |  sl(h::t, sum, len) = sl(t, sum + h, len + 1)
in 
 sl(l, 0, 0)
end;
```

This code gives me the average of an list, but now I have to compare every element in that list with the average and say how many elements are greater than the average and how many are lower than the average.

Could you please help me with this last step?

Answer (score 0):

Your `promedio` function fails on the empty input; `promedio []`, since it tries to divide by zero.

Here are two alternative ways to write this that takes empty lists into account:

```
(* Using one traversal *)
fun average xs =
    case foldl (fn (x, (sum, count)) => (x + sum, 1 + count)) (0, 0) xs of
         (0, 0) => 0
       | (x, y) => x div y

(* Using two traversals *)
val sum = foldl op+ 0
fun average [] = 0
  | average xs = (sum xs) div (length xs)
```

You can *partition* a list using any predicate with `List.partition`.

In your case, the predicate may be `x <= avg`.

```
fun partition_average xs =
    let val avg = average xs
    in List.partition (fn x => x <= avg) xs end
```

Notice that if I didn't bind `average xs` to `avg` outside the `fn x => ...`,

```
(* Don't do this *)
fun partition_average xs =
    List.partition (fn x => x <= average xs) xs
```

then I'd be recomputing `average xs` for each element of `xs`.

A demo:

```
- partition_average [1,2,3,4,5]; (* avg being 3 *)
> val it = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]) : int list * int list

- partition_average [1,2,3,9]; (* avg being 3(.75) *)
> val it = ([1, 2, 3], [9]) : int list * int list
```